# (Python) code to count weighted perfect matchings?

Tags: python, math, graph-theory

Forgive me if this question is better suited to mathoverflow or some other sister site.

I'm interested in counting the weighted sum of perfect matchings in a (not necessarily bipartite) planar graph.  This is a standard problem; it's frequently solved using the [FKT algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm).  I'd like to find some Python code to solve this (and am not eager to write it myself, because the algorithm is a little complicated).

Failing that, is there code available in some other (relatively mainstream) language?

User sabbahillel below suggested that I should list some of the software I've found that doesn't work, to avoid reduplication of effort.  To that end:

- [fkt](http://www.ohloh.net/p/libfkt) appears only to apply to *unweighted* graphs, and is in Gforth.
- [OBDD](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/programs.html) by Knuth (!) is only for unweighted bipartite graphs and is in CWEB.
- [vaxmaple](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/divers/software.html) requires Maple and [vaxmacs](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~dbwilson/vaxmacs/) is an Emacs mode (?!?!); neither support weighted or non-bipartite graphs.

Comment: The forth package appears to have explicit support for weighted graphs.  Read the code.

Answer (score 0):

google is your friend. I found a sourceforge project that implements this in FORTH

[FKT Alpha Count perfect matchings in planar graphs.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fkt/)

> Description: This project provides an implementation of the FKT
>   algorithm to count the number of perfect matchings in a planar graph.
>   The source code is written in the Forth language, requiring Gforth to
>   run. Computations can be perfored via a command line tool as well as
>   via a library usable with Gforth.

[Source Code](http://sourceforge.net/p/fkt/code/2/tree/trunk/)

Comment: Thanks, I'd found that too, but (1) it's for *unweighted* graphs, and (2) it's in Gforth.

Comment: @Bill Bradley OK just thought I would mention it in case it fit. You might want to mention what else you have found that does not apply to save time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm the author of the [FKT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fkt/) project on sourceforge.  FKT *does* come with support for weighted graphs.  FKT installs a command-line program that takes ASCII-descriptions of graphs as input, and outputs the computed number of matchings on stdout.  This interface allows for easy integration with other programming languages, such as Python.  Of course you need a Gforth installation on your system, but that shouldn't be a problem, all main-stream Linux distributions have Gforth packages in their repositories.

FKT does all computations in integer arithmetic over finite fields (modulo a chosen integer N).  That integer N is limited to a width of 31 or 63 bits, depending on your operating system.  If longer results are needed, you can invoke FKT multiple times with different (co)prime N_1..N_k, and then use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to determine the actual weighted count of matchings for your graph modulo N_1*...*N_k.

Note that the FKT algorithm does not determine the actual sign of the sum of matchings.  It only guarantees that all matchings are summed with the same sign.  So FKT outputs either -m or m (mod N), and after application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem the output is either -m or m (mod N_1*...*N_k).  Usually you know enough about your graph to know what sign to exepect.